# Best method to select values present in one table but missing in another one? ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

My solution:
Table name : HW1_PERSON, hw1_sfaff

```
SELECT I.ID,person.person_id
FROM HW1_PERSON
LEFT JOIN HW1_STAFF
ON     
I.ID=person.person_id
WHERE person.person_id IS NULL;
```

> ERROR at line 5: ORA-00904: "PERSON"."PERSONID": invalid identifier

Data Example:

```
INSERT INTO hw1_person (id, first_name, last_name, dob, address) VALUES (26, 'fname44', 'lname44', to_date('2/12/1990', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), '301 6th Av NJ');
INSERT INTO hw1_person (id, first_name, last_name, dob, address) VALUES (27, 'fname45', 'lname45', to_date('12/8/1982', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), '975 7th Av NJ');

INSERT INTO hw1_staff (person_id, emp_num, start_date, end_date, salary) VALUES (1, 'WZIAE', to_date('7/1/1965', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null,70000);
INSERT INTO hw1_staff (person_id, emp_num, start_date, end_date, salary) VALUES (2, 'EWEMU', to_date('11/18/1980', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), to_date('12/26/1970', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),80000);
INSERT INTO hw1_staff (person_id, emp_num, start_date, end_date, salary) VALUES (3, 'KJHSN', to_date('2/26/1991', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null,40000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from hw1_staff s
where not exists (
        select 1
        from hw1_person p
        where p.id = s.person_id
        )
```

It will select all the rows from staff which don't any corresponding row in person table.

Or perhaps you want the opposite i.e. all the persons which are not staff:

```
select *
from hw1_person p
where not exists (
        select 1
        from hw1_staff s
        where p.id = s.person_id
        )
```

If you want to use the JOIN based alternative to get persons which are not staff:

```
select *
from hw1_person p
left join hw1_staff s
    on p.id = s.person_id
where s.person_id is null
```

Comment: Thank you so much , what is this mean select 1 ?

Comment: Select 1 is just to satisfy the syntax of needing to "select something".

Comment: @LeeJohnny - `NOT EXISTS` doesn't care about what is being selected. It just check if there is a row or not. So, we are providing a constant 1 instead of any or all the columns,

Comment: @LeeJohnny - As OP, it's your right to accept whatever answer you want, but may I ask why you unaccepted my answer? The other answer is just stating out what I answered and that 7 mins later.

Comment: I like it , i jsut don't know i only can accept one answer

Comment: Can you answer me one more question pls?

Comment: SELECT code,Bld.address, M.first_name,M.L.Name,M.Address
   from hw1_building Bld
    JOIN hw1_person M
    ON Bld.address = M.Address
UNION ALL
SELECT M.first_name,M.L.Name,M.Address
FROM hw1_building Bld
JOIN hw1_person M
ON M.first_name = M.L.Name;
This is my solution for the question (List the building’s information along with its manager’s information) but it don't work

Comment: @LeeJohnny - This looks like an unrelated question. Please ask a new question providing the relevant information in it.

Comment: I solve the 90%the question HERE is my solution SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,D.DOB,M.SALARY
from HW1_PERSON M
inner join HW1_BUILDING Bld
ON M.id = Bld.id
INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
ON Bld.id = M.id
INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
ON M.id = Bld.id
Inner JOIN HW1_BUILDING Bld
ON Bld.id = M.id
INNER JOIN HW1_BUILDING C
ON M.id = C.id
INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON D
ON M.id = D.id
INNER JOIN HW1_STAFF M
ON M.id = Bld.id;

Comment: When i put the salary show 360 row  but before that was right rows to display, I don't know where i got wrong

Comment: I put my new solution on the top ,

Comment: @LeeJohnny - Please don't edit the same question to ask another one. This invalidates all the existing answers. Please ask a new question.

Comment: I can't not ask a new question when i finish i will fix it back sorry about that

Comment: @LeeJohnny - Why can't you ask a new question? See this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: I have the question limit .

Comment: It's hard to see what you're trying to do here. About your question limit, you probably have deleted many of your questions ([see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273741/stack-overflow-you-have-reached-your-question-limit)). I'd suggest you to open a new account and ask a new question providing sample data, expected output and current question that you're using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618106/error-at-line-1-ora-00904-s-salary-invalid-identifier This is my new account pls take a look ,thank you si much , my due is close thank you so mcuh

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your query.

You wrote:

```
FROM HW1_PERSON
LEFT JOIN HW1_STAFF
```

but to make your query work, it has to be:

```
FROM HW1_PERSON I
LEFT JOIN HW1_STAFF person
```

And as mentioned in the other answer; yes, you can use `NOT EXISTS` for your task.

Comment: can u answer me one more question?