# ORA-00904: invalid identifier in this instance

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Here is my solution, I want to display  all the information in 3 tables with salary, when I put salary at then end, no matter what I tried,I still got wrong. Someone help me fix. I don't know how to display the salary with only 15 rows.

```
SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,D.DOB,S.SALARY
    from HW1_PERSON M
    inner join HW1_BUILDING Bld
    ON M.id = Bld.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
    ON Bld.id = M.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
    ON M.id = Bld.id
    Inner JOIN HW1_BUILDING Bld
    ON Bld.id = M.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_BUILDING C
    ON M.id = C.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON D
    ON M.id = D.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,D.DOB,S.SALARY FROM HW1_STAFF S
    where S.SALARY = NULL
    ;
```

---

Here are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE HW1_PERSON (
     ID INT NOT NULL,
     FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
     LAST_NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
     DOB DATE,
     ADDRESS VARCHAR2(32),
     CONSTRAINT PK_HW1_PERSON_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE HW1_STAFF (
     SALARY DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
     START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
     END_DATE DATE DEFAULT NULL,
     EMP_NUM VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     PERSON_ID INT NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT PK_HW1_STAFF PRIMARY KEY (PERSON_ID),
     CONSTRAINT FK_STAFF_PERSON FOREIGN KEY(PERSON_ID) REFERENCES HW1_PERSON(ID));

CREATE TABLE HW1_BUILDING (
     ID INT NOT NULL,
     CODE VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     NAME VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
     ADDRESS VARCHAR2(32),
     MANAGER_ID INT,
     CONSTRAINT PK_HW1_BUILDING PRIMARY KEY (ID),
     CONSTRAINT FK_BUILDING_STAFF FOREIGN KEY(MANAGER_ID) REFERENCES HW1_STAFF(PERSON_ID));

CREATE TABLE HW1_EMPLOYEE (
     ID INT NOT NULL,
     PERSON_ID INT,
     BUILDING_ID INT,
     CONSTRAINT PK_HW1_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (PERSON_ID,BUILDING_ID),
     CONSTRAINT FK_STAFF_ID FOREIGN KEY(PERSON_ID) REFERENCES HW1_STAFF(PERSON_ID),
     CONSTRAINT FK_BUILDING_ID FOREIGN KEY(BUILDING_ID) REFERENCES HW1_BUILDING(ID));
```

---

DATA EXAMPLE

```
INSERT INTO hw1_person (id, first_name, last_name, dob, address) VALUES (1, 'fname11', 'lname11', to_date('7/27/1990', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), '527 15th Av CT');
INSERT INTO hw1_person (id, first_name, last_name, dob, address) VALUES (2, 'fname12', 'lname12', to_date('12/5/1966', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), '254 11th St CT');


INSERT INTO hw1_staff (person_id, emp_num, start_date, end_date, salary) VALUES (1, 'WZIAE', to_date('7/1/1965', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null,70000);
INSERT INTO hw1_staff (person_id, emp_num, start_date, end_date, salary) VALUES (2, 'EWEMU', to_date('11/18/1980', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), to_date('12/26/1970', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),80000);
INSERT INTO hw1_staff (person_id, emp_num, start_date, end_date, salary) VALUES (25, '00001', to_date('5/21/1994', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null,0);
INSERT INTO hw1_staff (person_id, emp_num, start_date, end_date, salary) VALUES (26, '00002', to_date('7/19/1985', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null,0);
```

Comment: There is no `S` alias in your first select before `UNION`. You need to find the salary equivalent in any of your M, Bld, C or D tables, or join the HW1_STAFF to the first select

Comment: CAN YOU SHOW ME?PLS

Comment: If you want people to help you you need to frame a decent question. Your sample data doesn't cover all the tables in your query and some of the records you have posted fail your integrity constraints. Also you need to explain what business logic you want your query to execute instead of expecting us to to infer the rules from your shonky code.

Comment: Cab u help me fix it ? my data cover all this question need

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,D.DOB, '0' AS S.SALARY
    from HW1_PERSON M
    inner join HW1_BUILDING Bld
    ON M.id = Bld.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
    ON Bld.id = M.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
    ON M.id = Bld.id
    Inner JOIN HW1_BUILDING Bld
    ON Bld.id = M.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_BUILDING C
    ON M.id = C.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON D
    ON M.id = D.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,D.DOB,S.SALARY FROM HW1_STAFF S
    where S.SALARY = NULL
    ;
```

I Your First Query Column is Not Exist S.SALARY so set Default is '0' OR ''

Comment: Not working.ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Why do you have this series of joins:  INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
    ON Bld.id = M.id
    INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
    ON M.id = Bld.id

Comment: This for the bulid id

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have made some unnecessary joins here.

You wrote

```
from HW1_PERSON M
inner join HW1_BUILDING Bld
ON M.id = Bld.id
INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
ON Bld.id = M.id
INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON M 
ON M.id = Bld.id
Inner JOIN HW1_BUILDING Bld
ON Bld.id = M.id
INNER JOIN HW1_BUILDING C
ON M.id = C.id
INNER JOIN HW1_PERSON D
ON M.id = D.id
```

but, if you had written this, then it would be enough

```
from HW1_PERSON M
inner join HW1_BUILDING Bld
ON M.id = Bld.id
INNER JOIN HW1_BUILDING C
ON M.id = C.id
```

Moreover, you have used both `M` and `D` as aliases of the same table `HW1_PERSON` - which causes error while executing the query

Secondly, as mentioned in comments, your first query doesn't contain `S.SALARY` column from `HW1_STAFF`. From your table structures, I think you can get the column by doing this in your first query.

```
SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,M.DOB,S.SALARY
from HW1_PERSON M
inner join HW1_BUILDING Bld
ON M.id = Bld.id
INNER JOIN HW1_BUILDING C
ON M.id = C.id
INNER JOIN HW1_STAFF S
ON S.PERSON_ID = M.id
```

Moreover, in your second query, you searched for `NULL` in `S.SALARY`, but by definition of your `HW1_STAFF` table, that column will not be null. So, in the second query, you will not get any result. Perhaps you should change that query - to something like this

```
SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,D.DOB,S.SALARY FROM HW1_STAFF S
where S.END_DATE = NULL
```

Then, the whole query will look something like this

```
SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,M.DOB,S.SALARY
from HW1_PERSON M
inner join HW1_BUILDING Bld
ON M.id = Bld.id
INNER JOIN HW1_BUILDING C
ON M.id = C.id
INNER JOIN HW1_STAFF S
ON S.PERSON_ID = M.id
UNION ALL
SELECT Bld.id,C.code,M.FIRST_NAME,M.LAST_NAME,Bld.Address,M.ADDRESS,M.DOB,S.SALARY FROM HW1_STAFF S
where S.END_DATE = NULL
;
```

Comment: How to  existing part of the first query because it show the FROM error and what should i change for show the salary?

Comment: you will write whatever you wrote in the `from` of the first query; then you will write the inner join part I wrote; then you will union with the second query.

Comment: In your second query, you can do `where S.END_DATE = NULL`; then I think you can get some result in the second query.

Comment: I wrote the second query , but i still got wrong by the from from < existing part of the first query > how should i begin to second query, i only put FROM IS SHOW ME WRONG

Comment: Thank for tried  but still get same mistake ON S.id = M.id
   
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00904: "S"."ID": invalid identifier

Comment: My bad. This time, I made a mistake. Edited again.

Comment: ERROR at line 12:
ORA-00904: "D"."DOB": invalid identifier     ERROR FROM LINE 12 NOW

Comment: `D.DOB` was used directly from your question. This basically means that the code in the question was with error. Anyways, corrected again.

Comment: It still have same error but I fix on my query now, i just put the primary right then it work , thank you anyway

Comment: Not sure how much I could help. Anyways, you are welcome.